# adobe edge embed

Tags: flash, adobe-edge

I have asked this question in the adobe edge forum but haven't received any replies so hope it is ok to ask it here.

I am looking for some advise on embedding an adobe edge animation into a web page.

It's more complex than it sounds unfortunately for me because I don't have any coding knowledge.

I have several web pages with a single version of the flash animation embedded into the web page. I want to add the edge animation to the same page but only play
if the device does not have or support the flash player. So, if flash is installed I want the flash version to run. If no flash (ipads, etc) then
the edge version should play. I know many people choose the other way around but while I am learning edge the flash version is much better so I would prefer the flash version to play primarily.

Onto the sound element. I have background music playing for the flash file (the music is built into the flash animation. I am not sure how I can do this with the edge animation. Presummably it would need to be coded into the acutal HTML page with some sort of
HTML5 tag? But the problem I see here is that if the flash version starts to play the HTML5 sound version would start to play too in browsers which support flash AND HTML5 tags.

I would appreicate any advise and if possible code examples on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you detect if the browser has flash or not

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
if(fo) hasFlash = true;
}catch(e){
if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian for the reply. Any idea how I can tell the browser to play the edge content if no flash is found? I have a real lack of coding knowledge so any advise is appreciated. Thanks